# -webkit-linear-gradient Not working in Dreamweaver CS6

Tags: html, webkit, adobe, dreamweaver

I've tried multiple times to apply the following piece of code in a CSS document:

```
display: block;
width: 500px;
margin: 500px auto;
padding: 15px;
text-align: center;
border: 4px solid blue;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,black,white);
outline: 7px solid red;
```

Everything appears correctly, except the gradient. I have CS6 Live View turned on, and it still refuses to appear. All I get in my box is a white background, as opposed to the black to white gradient. However, when I type the same line of code into the trial of Coda 2 I downloaded, it works perfectly. Is there anything I can do to resolve the issue?

Comment: What about internet explorer?

Comment: I didn't test it on IE. All I use is DW's Live View feature. Everything else works fine, except the gradient.

Comment: Why are you using DW's live view? remember that it's not a real browser. I'd recommend looking into LiveReload and Adobe Shadow to help you get things working. Once you've realised how awesome they are, try sublime text 2...

Comment: Try http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ to get a cross-browser gradient.

Comment: Thanks guys. I think I'll be making the move to Coda 2. I'm really impressed with the trial so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(255,255,255) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(255,255,255) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(255,255,255) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(255,255,255) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(255,255,255) 100%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0, rgb(0,0,0)),
    color-stop(1, rgb(255,255,255))
);
```

from : http://gradients.glrzad.com/